# Build command failed after running existing project on mac using npx react-native run-ios command

Tags: react-native

I tried to run an existing react-native project on mac to create ios build but i've been getting into an unusual error as mentioned below. I don't know what RCT-Folly does as i am new to react-native but i think the error is related to RCT-Folly, I tried many other stack answers but couldn't solve it
[Here is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ASm.png)

I have tried the other solution like creating a fresh projects and copying files, also tried reinstalling cocoapods,
If there is some other thread that you guys think i should try please let me know
Stuck at this for more than 3 days now!

Update:
After downgrading react native version it is now showing this error:

```
CompileC /Users/admin/Desktop/MTM/mindToMindfull\ 2/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTJSThread.o /Users/admin/Desktop/MTM/mindToMindfull\ 2/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTJSThread.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-Core' from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

RCT-Folly is an iOS Cocoapod library. Try cleaning your project first. From the project root, run (for Yarn)

1. `watchman watch-del-all && rm -f yarn.lock; rm -rf node_modules`,
   then
2. `yarn`
3. `cd ios && rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods Pods ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/; rm Podfile.lock; pod deintegrate; pod setup; pod install && cd ..`
4. `yarn ios`

I haven't used `npm` in awhile. But for 2 and 4, use `npm install` and `npx react-native run-ios`

Comment: I tried all 4 commands but the error is persistent 
now its giving 2 errors for RTC-Folly  
RCT-Folly/folly/net/NetOps.cpp
RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp
can i use any other library? or any version issue you think, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading react-native version 0.66.4
then installing pods and build was a success.